# ''comma+ with+ noun phrase'' tense confusion

Tags: participles, reduced-relative-clauses, participle-phrases

The problem here is the second part after the comma,

> The cigarette had drawn fire from critics ever since its popular introduction in the nineteenth century, *with many of those opposed to smoking **having voiced** important health concerns.*

1. I know, after '**with**' we can use either nouns or noun phrases in the above sentence. What is the bold part called? Is it a perfect participle or some passive form?
2. How to decide the verb forms and tenses within such sentences, in other words, why is it **having voiced** instead of **voicing**?

Comment: It would have been fine to say: "with many of those opposed to smoking voicing important health concerns"; however, this changes the meaning slightly.  Using "having voiced" means that the concerns had already been raised.  Using "voicing" means the concerns were being raised at the same time.  The former is better because it implies that smoking continued despite the fact that concerns had already been raised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *The cigarette had drawn fire from critics ever since its popular*
> *introduction in the nineteenth century, with many of those opposed to*
> *smoking* [*having voiced / voicing important health concerns*].

There's little to choose between the two constructions.

The perfect tense *having voiced important health concerns* conveys a past time meaning, tying the clause back to the period between the introduction of the cigarette and the 'drawing of fire' by the critics of its introduction, which you'll see is also expressed in a perfect clause.

The non-perfect *voicing important health concerns* conveys a similar meaning but is not tensed, leaving it open as to when those health concerns were actually expressed.

Personally, I prefer the latter construction.